# Search input on keyUp

Tags: javascript, css, user-input

I am trying to create a login form which will check the password strength and change the properties of a bar. Right now I'm trying to get it to simply check if the password input contains a single letter.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
<div id="strength">
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#pass").keyUp(function(){
    var pass = $("#pass");
    if(pass.val().indexOf("a") >= 0){
        $("#bar").css("width","70%");
    }
});
```

When I enter 'a' into the input box it doesn't alter the css though. Can someone please explain how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just watch your case, here's the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) Your original code has "keyUp" which fails, here I changed it to "keyup"

```
$("#pass").keyup(function(){
    var pass = $("#pass");
    if(pass.val().indexOf("a") >= 0){
        $("#bar").css("width","70%");
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/xnxp2qkk/).

Answer (score 1):

You have an uppercase `U` in your function call to `keyUp`. It should be all lowercase.

```js
$("#pass").keyup(function(){
    var pass = $("#pass");
    if(pass.val().indexOf("a") >= 0){
        $("#bar").css("width","70%");
    }
});
```

```css
#strength {width: 100%;}
#bar {height: 1em; background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="pass" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
<div id="strength">
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I do the same thing but for a range of inputs? For example, all characters from a-z and A-Z?

Comment: Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). See the answer from @itsgoingdown for an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/35708433/1028949

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#pass").on("keyup", function(){
        var $pass = $("#pass");
        if($pass.val().indexOf("a") > -1){
         $("bar").css("width","70%");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

try this, i hope it's your answer

```
$("#pass").on("keyup", function(){
    var $pass = $("#pass");
    if($pass.val().indexOf("a") != 0){
        document.getElementById('bar').style.width = 'y0%';
    }
});
```

Comment: How is this any different than what OP did? Also indexOf("a") != -1 not 0.

Comment: @noahnu sorry i change the answer.check it

Comment: I hnestly have no idea but it worked. I just replaced the "!=" with ">=" as I wanted it to be executed when it is not when it isn't